# Add a readme file to 'git archive' with commit hash

Tags: git

When releasing versions of code to the customer it would be helpful to know the specific commit a copy of the code came from.  Is it possible with 'git archive' to have the resulting .zip file include a readme.txt or some other indicator that shows the hash of the commit that was used?

I'm relatively new to git, having migrated from Mercurial.  In Hg when it generated an archive the zip would include an hg_archive.txt with the hash indicating exactly where the archive was generated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass git archive a filename parameter, in which you can include the short (or long) hash as part of the filename:

```
git archive -o "myrelease-$(git rev-parse --short HEAD).zip" HEAD
```

Would give you a filename of "myrelease-f12cb0d.zip"

If you want something more complex such as adding a readme file, you'll probably want to create a bash script that both creates the file with the current hash and creates an archive for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
git rev-parse --short HEAD > version.txt
tar . . .
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  I like this solution.  Only issue with your 2nd solution (the bash) script is that the zip doesn't include version.txt for some reason.  The file is there in my current directory, but it doesn't make it into the zip.  I could write version.txt and then just zip it manually.

Comment: Ah, true. Git archive won't take any uncommitted changes into account (writing to version.txt in this case). But, as you said, you could simply create the zip in the script instead of using git archive (minding that .git and .gitignore would need to be accounted for manually as well).

Answer (score 4):

It's already there. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive:

> In ZIP files commit ID is stored as a file comment.

Comment: If I right-click the file and look at properties, I see it on the Git tab, but that's only because I have TortoiseGit installed.  On a system without that I don't see anything on the normal file properties tab.  Is there another way to see this info?

Comment: I prefer to use command-line tools: `$ unzip -z SQLObject.zip  
Archive:  SQLObject.zip  
c230e9e8959da4447a578b6cfdb427eb17d43b5f`

Comment: Also available in tar archives, with a handy command to retrieve it: `git get-tar-commit-id < archive.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, Git 2.37 (Q3 2022) comes with a new option for `git archive`:

See [commit 15d8adc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15d8adccab9a3146b760b089df59ce3e7ca2b451), [commit 93e804b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93e804b2785e1f030737e31e7e18ddc997a368c7) (28 May 2022) by [Matthew John Cheetham (`mjcheetham`)](https://github.com/mjcheetham).
See [commit 0ed5b13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ed5b13f2450fd26c0e52cef775deea477e4cdb4), [commit aa5c79a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa5c79a33156c2f086ca3a149c11f1434d10f5ce), [commit b448557](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b44855743b1674caf3bd4f42814473771b129c48), [commit de1f68a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de1f68a968e64b3e1e2979222238fec1f045bbf3), [commit 237a1d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/237a1d138c4322a7e934f129dee02e2ea6a214cd) (28 May 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 23f2356](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23f2356fd902434a9b8e9e4cdae735f399c16ff0) (28 May 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 08baf19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08baf19fa316b8395bb0d984d66d438d233d2b5c), 07 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`archive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/237a1d138c4322a7e934f129dee02e2ea6a214cd): optionally add "virtual" files
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> With the `--add-virtual-file=<path>:<content>` option, [`git archive`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/237a1d138c4322a7e934f129dee02e2ea6a214cd/Documentation/git-archive.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive))</sup> now supports use cases where relatively trivial files need to be added that do not exist on disk.
>
> This will allow us to generate `.zip` files with generated content, without having to add said content to the object database and without having to write it out to disk.
>
> [jc: tweaked `<path>` handling] Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano gitster@pobox.com

`git archive` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/237a1d138c4322a7e934f129dee02e2ea6a214cd/Documentation/git-archive.txt#L54):

> value gets used by `--add-file` and `--add-virtual-file`.

`git archive` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/237a1d138c4322a7e934f129dee02e2ea6a214cd/Documentation/git-archive.txt#L66-L76):

> ### `--add-virtual-file=<path>:<content>`
>
> Add the specified contents to the archive.  Can be repeated to add
> multiple files.  The path of the file in the archive is built
> by concatenating the value of the last `--prefix` option (if any)
> before this `--add-virtual-file` and `<path>`.
>
> The `<path>` cannot contain any colon, the file mode is limited to
> a regular file, and the option may be subject to platform-dependent
> command-line limits. For non-trivial cases, write an untracked file
> and use `--add-file` instead.

That means in your case you can modify a `README` with `$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`: `--add-file`.
Or you can create (virtually) a dedicate "version" file: --add-virtual-file=version:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native way of adding a file to describe it but I don't see why not doing it manually yourself either if it is considered important on your project.

Generally this is not used since it is a bit redundant with the version (specially with some form of semantic versioning). Version numbers may be much more readable and meaningful than a commit hash for the final consumer. And in Git you generally mark versions with a tag, which serve themselves as pointers to certain commits.

Thus having an archive named `project-v0.1.2.tar.gz` is enough to find the commit with (i.e., among other possible commands):

```
$ git log -1 v0.1.2
0041db8e225cd1a8390509ceef3d162238983f94 (tag: v0.1.2) Commit description
```